making sale_line_id field invisible
I'm working on customizing Odoo and have encountered an issue with the sale_line_id field.
I'm inheriting the project.task model in my custom module (wsl_available_drivers). In view, I need to make the sale_line_id field invisible.
<record id="view_task_form2" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Project.task.view.form.inherit.available.drivers</field>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='user_ids']" position="before">
            <field name="first_user" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="Journey_start_date"/>
            <field name="recurring_task" invisible="1"/>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_line_id']" position="attribute">
           <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>

When attempting to hide sale_line_id using XPath, I receive an error stating that the field does not exist in the project.task model.
Upon further investigation:
I found that sale_line_id is related to the Task model, with relatedmodel pointing to sale.order.line.
However, I cannot locate the sale_line_id field within the sale.order.line model or its related modules.

Maybe you need to update your model if you can't find the object.

my module is always updated

The sale_project module adds two sale_line_id fields and the visibility of the field depends on the group to which the user belongs, the second field has an additional invisible attribute
The XPath expression will match the first node it finds. If you need to hide the two fields, add another XPath to target the second field
Example:
<record id="view_task_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">project.task.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_project.view_sale_project_inherit_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_line_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>

        <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_line_id'][2]" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
        
    </field>
</record>

For more details check the View resolution and Inheritance specs documentation sections

still same error "cannot be located in parent view"

@Kenly you need to add the inheritance mistake. the wrong view is inherited and probably the module sale_project is missing in the dependencies.

Inheriting from project.view_task_form2 should work as the priority is the same and will be resolved last, but I prefer to inherit (as you said) directly from the sale_project.view_sale_project_inherit_form view. Thanks @CZoellner

@RahmaBegag Check my edit and make sure you add sale_project to the depends entry of the module manifest ('depends': ['sale_project'],) as CZoellner pointed out.

@Kenly Could work, but it could also not work when the custom module was installed before sale_project was installed.

@CZoellner In this case, yes, and to avoid this, we need to add the sale_project to the module's dependencies to ensure that the module is installed before our module

thank you guys , the mistake i made , i added sale to dependencies instead of sale_project.                                                                                                                                          i did as u said @kenly and it achieved what i wanted.

Because your inheritance order is incorrect, you need to check if this field has already been read during inheritance.

how to do this?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
